# How to optimize QSqlQuery?

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery

I'm developing an app that executes many queries to a Microsoft SQL Server and I'm searching a way to optimize it.
I'd like to know if there's a difference of performance between these ways to do:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("SELECT name, salary FROM employee WHERE salary > 50000");
```

- 

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT name, salary FROM employee WHERE salary > 50000");
```

- 

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT name, salary FROM employee WHERE salary > 50000");
query.exec();
```

Alors I'd like to know if there's a way to get the execution time for each query?
Tranks for your help!

Comment: Hi, did you get your answer or something is missing? If you got, please select an answer, if not, please clarify what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there will be a significant difference amongst these alternatives. For performance instrumentation, you can always have your own RAII timer which you can then use anywhere.

For a brief reference implementation:

timetracer.h

```
class TimeTracer {                                                  
public:                                                                     
  TimeTracer(const QString &message);                         
  ~TimeTracer();                                                                                                             
                                                                            
private:                                                                    
  QString m_message;                                                     
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_start;                             
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_end;                               
};
```

timetracer.cpp

```
TimeTracer::TimeTracer(const QString &message)                                   
  : _message(message)                                                           
{                                                                               
  m_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();                                                         
}                                                                               
                                                                                
TimeTracer::~TimeTracer()                                                       
{                                                                               
  m_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();  
  std::cout << m_message.toStdString() << ": " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(_end - _start).count();  << "ms" << std::endl;                                                                     
}
```

Then, you could just do:

```
#include "timetracer.h"

void myMethod()
{
    TimeTracer timeTracer("QSqlQuery::query");
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT name, salary FROM employee WHERE salary > 50000");
}
```

Comment: Your timer emits a message using an uninitialised member in the constructor, I think the `cout` should be in the destructor

Comment: @Caleth: for sure, thanks. Just put it quickly together in half a min as at work :)